# How to write to one file from another at specific line?

Tags: java, file, filereader, filewriter

I want to copy all of content from one file to another existing file, to a specific line. 
[File 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nb5mf.png), [File 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iD5pw.png), [Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPXko.png)

I used FileWriter to write both files, now I don't know how to merge them like this. I know how to write from one to another file but only to append one files content to the end of another file. But I need it to copy one file's content to another but at specific line, like in example pics. In example if you look, content is copied between two brackets of class ({}). Any ideas?

Comment: You could split file 2 into two files and merge the three files one after the other. Otherwise you'd need to do some nasty line number hardcoding logic.

Comment: If I were to tell you there was a class called `LineNumberReader` which you could use to read a file line by line and which would also keep track of the line numbers for you, would that give you some ideas?

Comment: Thanks guy's, already tried this but it complicates my other parts of project, so I gave up. Also I realized that I don't need these files separated, so now I make only one file with all of content. Thanks any way :)